# Memory error while trying out sequential keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, sequential

**Pre-info:**
So I read and learned about Keras-sequential model and wanted to try it out. So I read the [keras.sequential's official documentation](https://keras.io/api/models/sequential/) documentation and carried out the code to identify if the image is a cat or not with some youtube's help.

So after this I read [this medium post on Plant Disease identification](https://towardsdatascience.com/plant-ai-plant-disease-detection-using-convolutional-neural-network-9b58a96f2289) and wanna try it out. I downloaded the dataset given in that post and followed the code similarly.

**Main Issue:**
So I after the imports and everything when i ran, the code appends the image to a list:

```
if image_directory.endswith(".jpg") == True or image_directory.endswith(".jpeg") == True:
      image_list.append(convert_image_to_array(image_directory))
```

So when I run the code, it consumes my 99% memory (I can't even move the cursor) and after a minute or so, it throws me an error: out of memory. And 1 time I when I ran the code, my PC froze and I ran into BSoD.

**My PC Config:**

- Intel i5 8th Gen
- 8GB DDR4 RAM | 1TB HDD | free space upto 520GB
- 4GB nVIDIA GTX1050 Ti

Although after that, I resolved this issue by cv2.resize() the image from "256x256" to "64x64" and now it's only consuming 92% of my memory. **But what I'm trying to ask is why is this happening?** There are some 31k images each of almost 10-11KB, so total it sums upto 370MB, so even if it should load all the images on my memory, it shouldn't exceed 400MB, why is it consuming all of my 8GB of RAM?

Comment: Does the code for cnn works on gpu or cpu?

Comment: @colt.exe CPU, I don't know how to load the code onto GPU.

Comment: It's not the images that takes your RAM. Your code is being loaded to CPU that does sequential operation whereas GPU does it parallel. Install nvidia-drivers and type nvidia-smi. Then, you can put your code printing what CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES are present. Write command CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=(GPU_ID) python code.py

Comment: Your calculations about memory size are completely incorrect, a single 256x256 RGB floating point image is 0.75 MB (uncompresed, as represented in a numpy array), so 31K of those will require around 23.3 GB of RAM, which is clearly more than what you have.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, wow, but under file-properties it shows the imgae size to be 10KB. I checked the same thing with most images. Then I saw even the file-properties (of image folder) and it said 376MB. Hence I thought that way. Anyways, I'll look it up on google if what you're saying is true then. Thanks a ton.

Comment: The file size is not the same as the size in memory after the image has been uncompressed and loaded into memory. Also if you resize the images to 256x256, that requires more memory than the original size of the images.

Comment: @AkashKumar Actually, it is the images that are filling the RAM, not sure why you would think otherwise.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Doesn't the CPU load and feed images to GPU batchwise? Images takes the RAM, but the matrix operations involved takes up your GPU memory. Both the parameters comes to play, isn't that so? For parallel instruction processing, GPU is required.

Comment: @AkashKumar Not if the code is actually loading all images directly into RAM, this is exactly what the OPs code is doing.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks. If we use flow_from_directory with batch_size 32, then the code should be able to run. Is that right?

Comment: @AkashKumar, as a matter of fact, I did use that: `model.fit_generator(img_gen_obj.flow(xtrain, ytrain, batch_size=32),validation_data=(xtest,ytest),steps_per_epoch=len(xtrain)//32,epochs=epochs)`

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy, sorry I didn't get the computation: If I load a 256x256 image with 3 channels and considering every channel took 8 bit = 256x256x24 bits = 192KB !! How Does it ends up being 23.3GB? I took reference from here: https://4nsi.com/faq/how-do-i-calculate-the-file-size-for-a-digital-image#:~:text=Step%202%3A%20Multiply%20total%20number,the%20file%20size%20in%20kilobytes.

Comment: @AkashKumar, anyways, doesn't Keras by default load the model and data on GPU and train it on GPU as well?

Comment: @ShashankShukla 192Kb sounds right for an 8-bit per pixel image, I multiplied by 4 to get the floating point image size (0.75 MB. as each channel is 4 bytes), and then multiply by 31K to get the total memory used by all images, as I assume that you are loading all images (or enough images to trigger an out of memory error)

Comment: Note that we are speculating here because you did not include your actual code and error message, which are actually important.  Your code is only similar to the medium post as you say, not exactly the same.

Comment: @ShashankShukla do you have tensorflow-gpu installed? Do you have the required NVIDIA toolkits installed? What's your output of nvidia-smi, pip list, etc.? As Dr. Snoopy mentioned without these information, we can't tell even if your code is running on GPU or not.